# Event sourcing with inconsistent behavior of events

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am trying to implement an event sourcing system using Postgres.
Best way to explain is by example.
So let's assume my events need to eventually describe a person.
And I have the following events:

1. PersonCreatedEvent(value = 100, field = "id", date = ..)
2. AgeUpdated(value = 10, field = "age", date = ..)
3. LastNameUpdate(value = "newLastName", field = "lastname", date = ..)
4. LocationUpdated(value = (lat, long), field = "location", date = ..)
5. BalanceUpdated(value = 1000, field = "balance", date = ..)

Event 1 will happen only once in a lifetime of a person.
Events 2 - 3 Can happen several times.
Events 4 - 5 Can happen many many times.

At the end of the day, I will end up with a table that is consistent mainly with events 4 and 5.

So if I have 10 million people in my table, I might have billions of events while 99% of them are basically 4, and 5. This will result in a huge data store, not sure that Postgres will play with it nicely.( it can.. but with significant work \ infrastructure increase.)

This is only an example, my entity might be combined of 100 fields, which means at least 100 events per entity. some of the fields have the characteristics of events 4 and 5.

The added value of using event sourcing in my case is that I get a history inherently on my entity, which is a product requirement in my case.

What is the best practice in this case? 
Maybe more frequent properties should be handled elsewhere?

**UPDATE**:
Another example is to look on a device aggregate.

1. DeviceManufacturerUpdated(value = "cisco", field = "manufacturer", date = ..)
2. DeviceNameUpdated(value = "foo", field = "name", date = ...)
3. DeviceIpUpdated(value = "1.1.1.1", field = "ip", date = ...)
4. DeviceLocationUpdated(value = "new location", field = "location", date = ...)
5. DeviceLastSeenUpdated(value = "some date", field = "last_seen), date = ...)

Same here 
1. event 1 can heppen one time
2. event 2 can heppen several times
3. event 3 may heppen every day
4. event 4 may heppen several times a day
5. event 5 may heppen every minute

if I am implementing this over postgress I will end up with a huge table mostly contains events 4 and 5.

Comment: snapshot might help, but I assume in certain point I will need to do something with the size of my database. (The size is a result of the "type" of events I am persisting). So at some point will be left with a snapshot but I will lose the history capabilities (after deleting events). It feels like I am doing something wrong when my table consists of 99% the same event type. it feels like there is a room for an optimization I am not aware of..:-| what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

For me it seems that you have a (granular) CRUD system and you don't need [Event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). This is not bad, you just don't need to reconstruct the state by reapplying all the events from the history in order to validate the commands. In your case, *maybe* the current state is enough.

If you like the idea of events (more like if you *need*) then you could use an [Event log](https://medium.com/@marco_be/cqrs-without-event-sourcing-but-most-likely-with-an-event-log-94fb5a5b5b84). This is like Event sourcing but you use events in a eventually consistent manner and only for the Read side.

In any case, in order to split entities by behavior, you could use [DDD](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/). Maybe you could have two Aggregates that share the same ID: `PersonDetails` and `PersonAccountBalance`? Why? Because you don't ever need the person's name (or location)  when you check that his balance should be positive when you update his balance (about that, it's weird that you `update his balance` and not `makeADeposit` or `withdrawMoney` but it depends on your domain).

Comment: Thanks! I think the BalanceUpdated was a little missleading...it was a bad example. using event sourcing made sense when I wanted to get history for person, and describe him at any point of time. Let's address aggregate person. If it has a property that get updated very frequently, should it be addressed diffrenetly? I mean, it feels that something is wrong when my table consists of 99% of the same event type,

Comment: @Tomer It really depends on each case. I need to know the exact business details in order to say it for sure...

Comment: You are totally right. I added an example which represent better my use case. Tell me what you think.

Comment: @Tomer I recommend that you emit events only if something really changed inside your aggregate otherwise don't emit anything, just return void, that is a perfect valid situation. For example, don't emit `DeviceLocationUpdated` unless the location really changed, it has a new different value. But keep in mind my answer about your CRUD-ish domain.

Comment: Of course, the events are generated only if the current state is different that the one I got. this may heppen many times. I think the main question is if it's better to use event sourcing to get the history of the device in this case. or should it be implemented in a different way, like 2 tables, 1 the current state, and the otehr an history table

Comment: @Tomer If the history of events is relevant to the command validation done by the Aggregate then yes otherwise no. As I wrote in the answer, an Event log could be enough.

Answer (score 2):

> my entity might be combined of 100 fields, which means at least 100 events per entity

That *probably* indicates that your events model your entities at the wrong grain.  One "thing" happening in the domain that affects 100s of properties should normally appear in your history as one event with a lot of data, rather than many events with one datum each.

That's not to say that you won't end up with a potentially large number of events, especially if you have a lot of entities.

There are two common answers to this.  One borrows from [domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design); we think about the domain in terms of aggregates - collections of state that can be isolated from each other.  Because the entities can be isolated, it doesn't matter if they are in the same durable store, or if the store is sharded.  So you can distribute the events.

Another possibility - in many domains, there is a natural temporal rhythm; at the end of the fiscal year, you roll up the current state, use that state to mark the beginning of a new stream, and retire the old.

There's also the possibility of garbage collection - with the right data structures in place, you can have background processes grind through the history, replacing low value events.

The main thing is to get away from the notion of crud sourcing.

More broadly, you also need to think about whether or not the business derives value from tracking the entire history of an entity.  You shouldn't be using event histories for entities where the cost/benefit analysis is telling you to store information in document snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks strange to have an AgeUpdated and BalanceUpdated event in the same aggregate root. Events that has *Something*Updated in their name whispers to me that it is either a CRUD use-case or that you need to work more on your aggregate design.

Is there another grouping of transactions that can be interesting instead of the Person? To figure this out you should think of which *invariants* that should hold. That is, in which situations can the transaction fail and what should always be true? (Read up on domain-driven-design aggregates if you haven't)

If you're making some kind of transaction for account for example, maybe the business rule is that the account cannot be overdrawn by more than $100. In this case you *could* use the Account as the aggregate root instead of the Person owning the account.

To get the full balance for a person, you would need a *read-model* that aggregates everything for a user.

But everything depends on your use-case.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I think the BalanceUpdated was a little missleading. beacuse it indeed don't belong to the person aggregate. Let's asssume for a second that the event is related to Person aggregate (maybe locationupdated is better?), how should I handle a case in which this event is indeed in the right place, but it's frequency is *100 greater then the other events?

Comment: It depends what your concern is. I think it's not inherently wrong to have many similar events for an aggregate root. If you worry about performance, make sure you measure that it really is a problem before implementing something more complex such as snapshots. If you want to experiment with your domain logic without building too much infrastructure it would be cool if you wanted to try out our new service https://serialized.io for building CQRS/ES applications (I am one of the co-founders).